# CMake C# project "unsafe" property

Tags: c#, cmake

I am using CMAKE to generate c# project, and I want the project to have "Allow unsafe code", this can be set by :

- Project properties in Visual Studio.
- "Build" tab.
- Check "Allow unsafe code".

But I want to do it from CMAKE directly so I don't have to change it manually.

Is there any way to set it from CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: Have you tried `target_compile_options(<target> PUBLIC "/unsafe")`? Otherwise could you please a [mcve] of CMake code?

Comment: yes, it worked, would you please add it as an answer so I can accept it, thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Turning my comment into answer*

You need to know the corresponding compiler command line option - in this case [`/unsafe`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ct597kb0(v=vs.110).aspx) - and add it via the [`target_compile_options()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_compile_options.html) command:

```
target_compile_options(<target> PUBLIC "/unsafe")
```

*Note*: In this case `PUBLIC` means that this target (e.g. a library) is propagating the compiler option to all other targets in the project linking it. If you don't want this behavior, declare it `PRIVATE` instead.